# Detect focusOut of entire component

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a suggestions component that basically will have the following functionality:

- It has a text input
- Once this text input gets focused it will show up a div under it with some info and links
- This div has many p tags on it and some a tags.
- When the focus goes out of the ENTIRE component it should hide the div

I've tried to write the focusOut event of my component like this:

```
focusOut: function(event, view){
  if (!$.contains(this.$('.autocomplete-group')[0], event.relatedTarget))
    this.set('showingSuggestions', false)
}
```

Basically it will see if the new focused item (event.relatedTarget) is inside the outer DIV of my component (wich has the autocomplete-group class).

This works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox nor IE. It turns out that FF does not fill the relatedTarget property.

Then I tried a solution that did not make e happy (cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)). It did not make me happy because hooking an event to the entire document doesn't seem right. Anyways it did not work as well.

My question is if there's a good, simple, cross browser way to simply detect if the focus went out of my entire component.

Comment: I just checked the activeElement in another runloop. By that time the render queue will be done. https://github.com/blessenm/ember-cli-bm-select/blob/master/addon/components/bm-select.js#L155

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the code in a new runloop using `Em.run.later`. Here is the sample of a code for one my addons. I am hiding a dropdown menu when focus goes out of the component.

```
lostFocus: function() {
    if(this.get('isOpen')) {
      Em.run.later(this, function() {
        var focussedElement = document.activeElement;
        var isFocussedOut = this.$().has(focussedElement).length === 0 
                && !this.$().is(focussedElement);

        if(isFocussedOut) {
          this.closeOptions({focus:false});
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  }.on('focusOut'),
```

Running the code in a separate runloop will ensure that you will get the document.activeElement correctly